# How to make dendrograms with legends on left side with dendextend package?

Tags: dendextend

Good Afternoon
I have SNP genotypying dataset with 469 individuals in 1st column and their population information in 2nd column and rest of the columns is marker data. Now i want to make dendrogram with legends on leftside of dendrogram using dendextend package. I succeed mostly but i am not getting expected tree i am getting error like this
Error in legend("topleft", legend = levels(pop_type), fill = cols_6) : 
  'legend' is of length 0
here i am sharing my code and data can anyone help me to solve this problem? any help in this regard is highly appreciated
code - https://www.dropbox.com/s/4tfwyqvkqeri1k0/code%20to%20make%20dendrograms%20with%20labels%20on%20topleft%20-%20Copy.txt?dl=0
data - https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy9se9a6qi80985/DAPC3%20-%20Copy1.csv?dl=0
I have  different populations in my data set and i followed tutorial from this address
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/FAQ.html#color-side-bar-dendrogram-plot
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you create a simpler self-contained R code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Dear Tal galili sorry my late reply please find my code dropbox link i think it is still active. Actually i have 6 different population types and i want each population name as legend on my dendrogram. Thanks lot for your help

Comment: Your question requires some more work. Please make sure you extend your question to include all the needed information so that people would answer it.
Please read first the two following guides on how a good question should be written, this will help to ensure that you will get the assistance you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated